# c++ Including Qprocess [Fixed]

Tags: c++, qt, include, qprocess

Ive installed the qt.io stuff and in my project settings ive done the following:

Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories
Ive added: C:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\include

Properties -> C/C++ -> Addition Include Directories
Ive added: C:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\include

But it still says Cannot open source file

[image: cannot open src file]

Fixed the issue by including C:\Qt\6.2.0\mingw81_64\include\QtCore

Comment: first of all, you need to check if QMake or qt version is valid or not. it seems to be a qmake path error.

Comment: It seems you're using a minGW build of Qt with Visual Studio/MSVC. That won't work, you need a VS build of Qt. Also, the headers are in subdirs of include/, such as include/QtCore/QObject. I'd strongly suggest to use a build system to detect and configure Qt instead of configuring include paths (and later lib paths and names) manually.